# How to deserialize a csv file into a map w/ Jackson

Tags: java, collections, jackson, stream

I have a `CSV` file that I want to deserialise into an object with `Jackson`.

```java
class Foo{

   string x, y, z;

}
```

I can deserialise it into a `List<Foo>`. But is there a way to deserialise it into a `Map<String, Foo>`? Where the key is one of the members in `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert it to `Map` after deserialisation:

```
List<Foo> list = deserialiseToList();
Map<String, Foo> map = list.stream().collect(
  Collectors.toMap(Foo::getProperty, Function.identity()));;
```

Where `getProperty` is a member of a `Foo` class.

See:

- [Java 8 Collectors toMap](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collectors-tomap)